# Mosaic to New Raster; Mosaic Function changes colors of images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I am working with a 5 band multispectral image with uneven lightening.

I clipped the disturbed area out, corrected it, then tried to insert it back into the image.

When I try to combine the two images using either Mosaic or Mosaic to New Raster or in a mosaic dataset, one image is all black and the other is all white or one image is RGB and the other one is blue and white.

Any advice on how I can mosaic these two images together?

Here is a photo of the issue I am having:
[image]

Here is the photo of what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just needed to preprocess the raw data. The image then was fine.

Comment: The answer to the problem was to preprocess my imagery.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn’t notice this was an answer.